# Type hint Page Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I want to type hint a page variable as a function param, but i got a compilation error.

`sync function than_func(page:Page)
                             ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token:`

Comment: It seems that you are tring to run typescript code directly. You should compile it to plain js first. See for example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are tring to run typescript code directly. You should compile it to plain js first. See for example [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html).